# Can (severe) hypothermia happen at ambient temperatures of about 10 °C?

Tags: air-temperature, hypothermia

Suppose it's raining (abundantly) and/or the victim is very lightly dressed

Hypothermia usually occurs at very low temperatures, but it also depend on many other parameters than temperature, and as we know, heat is lost 25 times more rapidly when in contact with water than with air, and I heard that when a person is immerged in a 0° cold water, death occurs within only 15 minutes ...

So what I wanted to know if there is a risk for a person to suffer from a severe and eventually fatal hypothermia in such conditions (10 °C ambient, rainy, very lightly dressed)

Comment: Hypothermia is so severe, that even at 18 degrees (Celsius), paramedics are advised to cover patients in rescue blankets.

Comment: What has your research found so far? Hypothermia charts describing the time vs. temperature relationship are easily found with a simple web search.

Comment: My research ? Well repetitive stuff about BODY temperature, first aid stuff, etc., almost nothing about AMBIENT temperature, that of the surroundings, of the air, of the environment ... I am not sure if the term "ambient" is appropriate or clear enough, apparently not judging from the first comment, I edited the post hoping to make it clearer

Comment: Time vs temperature relationship that would be the kind of things I am looking for, I found no such thing in my researches, maybe it is because we do not use the same language and search engine.

Comment: Your research problem seems to be that most hypothermia charts were developed for cold water immersion situations, probably because that's easier to study. Out of water there are far more variables to consider such as wind, sunlight, clothing, rain/snow, etc. I found an easy yes/no answer to your question, but It doesn't make much of an answer. So I'm going to upvote this and hope someone can find better info.

Comment: Exactly, there are too many parameters that can affect the outcome, it's not the kind of things that can come from straight studies, it's one of the reasons that made me think I won't find what I am looking for with a simple web search. It would rather come from physicians opinions and reported cases. From there one has to extrapolate to have an idea about the question, it won't be very precise in any case would it ?

Comment: However probably all of the reported hypothermia incidents happened in very cold weather. One source stated that hypothermia can also occur in mild weather, but that's all, it says nothing more about it. Any information provided is welcome, besides the conditions I have described can't be considered equivalent to water immersion, but it gets somewhat close, the person would be soaked. Thanks anyway.